# Warning 'The API interface has changed' when running Karma on grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, karma-runner

When running karma from a grunt task I get the following warning:

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
Warning: The api interface has changed. Please use 
  server = new Server(config, [done])
  server.start()
instead. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I have tested running karma with my configuration, both using the 'run' and 'start' karma commands and they seem to work fine.

Using `grunt --force` can complete the task, but it completes with warnings.

This are the versions that I'm currently using:

- Karma 0.13.0
- Grunt 0.4.5
- grunt-cli 0.1.13
- node.js 0.12.7
- npm 2.11.3

The project was generated using yeoman (1.4.7) but I have the same problem using Karma in a separate project with just jasmine, karma and Grunt (also tested it with Gulp).

I have searched for the warning message but found nothing. I don't know if this is the expected behavior or if there is another way of completing the tasks without warnings.

Comment: what does the grunt task look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the [grunt-karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma) plugin to start the Karma tests from Grunt, you need to update the `grunt-karma` dependency in your `package.json` file to *0.12.0*:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "grunt-karma": "~0.12.0",
  ...
}
```

Version 0.12.0 of grunt-karma was released earlier today, and it uses the new API: https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma/releases

Answer (score 5):

They changed with new version here:

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes

```
var Server = require('karma').Server;
var config = {
    configFile: path.join(__dirname, '/../karma.conf.js'),
    singleRun: singleRun,
    autoWatch: !singleRun
};

var server = new Server(config, done)
server.start()
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - while it adds further detail to the issue, it does not provide a fix for starting the test execution from Grunt.

Comment: This helped me solve the issue I had with gulp.  Although, @nwinkler is right that this doesn't exactly answer the question in its current form.  It is still extremely valuable information.  Perhaps some merging of the accepted answer and this one would be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Gulp and I had to either setup my test task as follows:

```
var Server = require('karma').Server;

gulp.task('test', function (done) {
  new Server({
   configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
   singleRun: true
  }, done).start();
});
```

or roll the karma version back to `0.10.0` to get it working. At this time there is not pull request on [gulp-karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma) to change how this works, but not sure if there will be a change in the future.

Here is a helpful example that was updated after the Karma API change: https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Yeoman's generator-angular like I was, you'll need to switch it out in your grunt-karma.js file.

Replace `var server = require(‘karma’).server;`

with `var Server = require('karma').Server;`

and then at the bottom of the file in the else block instead of `server.start(config, done);`

you'll find `server.start(data, finished.bind(done));`

just put `var server = new Server(data, finished.bind(done));` right above it and it should work fine.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that anymore - the grunt-karma plugin was updated shortly after you posted your answer.